# ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 37

Tags: mysql

Query `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 'Omnion' AND disable_flag = '0'`

this Query working fine in the Localhost,

after uploaded into server, it gives the problem

```
Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

    ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 37
    STR: '
    SQL: SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = \'Omnion\' AND disable_flag = \'0\'
     LIMIT 0, 30 

    SQL query: 

    SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = \'Omnion\' AND disable_flag = \'0\' LIMIT 0, 30

    MySQL said: 

    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'Omnion\' AND disable_flag = \'0\'
    LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

Please help me,

Thank you

Comment: When you trying run this SQL in your code, you got also error? or only in phpmyadmin is this error?

Comment: @OTARIKI , In php code and also in phpmyadmin same error

Comment: Check the datatype of disable_flag. If it is an Int then remove the quoations.

Comment: @rbenitez, 'disable_flag' datatype is int(11), i remove the quotations still same error

Comment: how about using double quote for string 'Omnion'?

Comment: @rbenitez, same error for double quote also

Comment: Oh that's weird. Have you tried 
     SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "Omnion" AND disable_flag = 0

Comment: @rbenitez, same issue

Comment: I think you are using an old version of phpMyAdmin. Try updating and if you are using PHP, use addslashes().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update version of phpMyAdmin, see this link: [phpMyAdmin Bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=725123)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Whenever I issued a SQL command that contained a quote in it, it was giving me "ERROR: Unclosed quote". My phpMyAdmin version is 2.11.9.6 and the MySQL version is 5.1.55. After much frustration and research and I resolved it as follows:

The error was occurring only if I use the phpMyAdmin using the link provided on my Yahoo MySQL database panel. I found out that I can access the phpMyAdmin administration tool directly without going through the link provided on the Yahoo Web Hosting MySQL database panel. To go directly to phpMyAdmin,
    www.yourdomain.com/phpmyadmin

It will open up the administration panel that looks similar to the one opened up from the Yahoo MySQL database panel. You log in using the same MySQL database user id and password. The SQL commands work perfectly fine from this panel.

Note: If you do not have the www.yourdomain.com/phpmyadmin sub directory, you may have to install the phpMyAdmin tool by going to the Web Hosting Control Panel/Other Site Building Tools, etc...